# Making a "ping" inside of my C# application

Tags: c#, ping

I need my application to ping an address I'll specify later on and just simply copy the Average Ping Time to a .Text of a Label.

Any help?

EDIT:

I found the solution in case anyone is interested:

```
Ping pingClass = new Ping();        
PingReply pingReply = pingClass.Send("logon.chronic-domination.com");
label4.Text = (pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms");
```

Comment: Add your answer and a link to the relevant MSDN documentation as a proper answer instead of updating the question.  You get reputation that way and it keeps the format of the QA consistent.  Relevant MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give a look the [NetworkInformation.Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class.

An example:

*Usage:*

```
PingTimeAverage("stackoverflow.com", 4);
```

*Implementation:*

```
public static double PingTimeAverage(string host, int echoNum)
{
    long totalTime = 0;
    int timeout = 120;
    Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

    for (int i = 0; i < echoNum; i++)
    { 
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (host, timeout);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            totalTime += reply.RoundtripTime;
        }
    }
    return totalTime / echoNum;
}
```

Comment: PingTimeAverage ("i.dont.exist.com", 1000) == 0

Comment: @Anton, if the host cannot be resolved, the Ping.Send method will throw a PingException... http://is.gd/2hLjo

Comment: @CMS I've tried replicating a small test for Ping(), and using "hostname.com" won't work for anything, stackoverflow.com/google.com or whatever. The only time Ping works, is with the actual IP. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send.aspx) for Ping says you can use hostname though...

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sidenote to this. There is allready a project on sourceforge doing about that what you want. This has also included an implementation of ICMP (RFC 792)

[Sourceforge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pingutil/)