# C# - Remote ping from another server

Tags: c#, windows-services, ping, remote-server

I have a scenario with 3 servers: `A`, `B` and `C`. The server `A` contains a C# Windows Service that regularly pings servers `B` and `C`. The problem is that server A doesn't reach server `C` (firewall issues). Server `B` reaches server `C` with no problem.

Is it possible, programmatically in C#, from the Windows Service on server `A`, to log on in server `B` and ping server `C`?

Comment: the answer is yes, but you need more details/code for it to be good SO question. There is also likely better ways to do what you want (serverfault.com maybe place to ask you actual question).

Comment: I'm using this code to execute the ping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800958/using-ping-in-c-sharp

Comment: Server A is Windows, servers B and C are Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could telnet into server B and ping C, and capture the output.

Comment: I mean programmatically with C#, not manually..

Comment: Well, since ping can only happen from one host to another, you need a work-around. There will have to be a piece of software on B which will perform the actual ping to C.

Comment: +1: @Fernando - how "telnet into server B" is not valid suggestion? Telnet is very simple protocol to use and can be used from C# code just fine. Note: I'd build webservice/site instead of enabling telnet (similar to many remote ping/proxy services on the net).

Comment: Alexei - I didn't know it is possible to telnet the server B from A and execute a ping from B to C. Do you know how to do that with C#?